# NoSuchMethodException while sending email in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail

I have spring boot application with Gradle.

This is my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:'+ jaxbVersion)
    compile('org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:' + apacheFOPVersion)
    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:' + amazonS3Version)
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:' + commonsLangVersion)
    compile('commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:' + commonsFileUploadVersion)
    compile('org.springframework:spring-test:4.3.13.RELEASE')
    compile('net.authorize:anet-java-sdk:' + anetSDKVersion)
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:' + swaggerUiVersion)
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:' + swaggerUiVersion)
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')
    compile files('../models/build/libs/quickboard.models-' + modelsVersion + '.jar')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile("com.intuit.quickbooks-online:ipp-v3-java-data:3.0.0")
    compile(group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'ipp-v3-java-devkit', version: '3.0.5', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies')
            {
                exclude group: 'javax.mail', module: 'mailapi'
            }
    compile(group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'oauth2-platform-api', version: '3.0.5', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies')
            {
                exclude group: 'javax.mail', module: 'mailapi'
            }
    compile group: 'com.ecwid', name: 'maleorang', version: '3.0-0.9.6'
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.5.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'javax.mail'
}
```

and this is my code for sending the email

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myemail@domain.com"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(toEmail, emailSubject));

            msg.setSubject(emailSubject);
//            msg.setText(message);
            msg.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(msg);
```

on `Transport.send(msg);` line I am getting the exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger;)V
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.initStreams(SMTPTransport.java:2016) ~[javax.mail-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1936) ~[javax.mail-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654) ~[javax.mail-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313) ~[ipp-v3-java-devkit-3.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172) ~[ipp-v3-java-devkit-3.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121) ~[ipp-v3-java-devkit-3.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190) ~[ipp-v3-java-devkit-3.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120) ~[ipp-v3-java-devkit-3.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
```

I Read every topic regarding this exception and mostly the case was that some dependencies were including old versions of `mailapi` dependency and added this exclusions in my `build.gradle` too.
I am checking dependency tree(compile time and runtime) in **Intellij idea** and only `jaxa.mail` dependency is presented which I have in `build.gradle` none of any other dependency includes it, but I am still getting this exception.

Do you have any other suggestion what should I try and what may be reason ?

Comment: Could you run `mvn dependency:tree` and share the output with us?

Comment: It is gradle project, so this command is not working

Comment: If `./gradlew app:dependencies` can be run, could you share the output?

Comment: Remove your mail dependencies and add `spring-boot-starter-mail` as a dependency.

Comment: @cafertayyar it is too long and can not comment whole class path, but believe me this is the only dependency +--- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.0
|    \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1   where word "mail" appears

Comment: @M.Deinum  I deleted  ```compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.5.0'``` and added  ```compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')``` , but getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downgraded dependency `compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.5.0'` to  `compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.4.5'`
and it works now, also looks like it is not necessary to exclude `mailapi` from dependencies and

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'javax.mail'
}
```

code works fine with or without these excludes